# Symfony - directly access the class properties

Tags: php

I have created small method in entity class where I can change some things within two fields:

This is my Fruit Entity method:

```
 /**+
 * @return $this
 */
public function freeBasket(): Fruit
{
    $this->setFreshBasketName($this->getBasketName());
    $this->seBasketName(null);
    return $this;
}
```

But I got an idea that since this is inside Fruit class, there is no need to use methods for it, that there is a way I can directly access the class properties and than remove `setFreshBasketName()` method.

How can I accomplish that? New with Symfony. :)

Comment: Has nothing to do with either Symfony or Doctrine. This is basic PHP knowledge and [property access](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
public function freeBasket(): Fruit
{
    $this->freshBasketName = $this->getBasketName();
    $this->basketName = null;
    return $this;
}
```